# How to color different words in a RichTextBox with different colors?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to color *sections* of a RichTextBox differently?

```
string text = "a b c d teste";

// words to highlight
string[] word = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

// colors to use, aligned with words above
Color[] color = { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.BlueViolet, Color.Brown };

for(int c = 0,size = word.Length; c < size; c++) {
    //search by color[x] and set line color to color[x]
    //How I do this?
}
```

Comment: what control are you using to display the text?

Comment: Do you have a question? I can't tell what you want.

Comment: I updated the question to ... have a question. I changed it to "sections", from "lines" -- the difference is just in determining the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use RichTextBox to color your lines of text, use this snippet.

```
txtRichTextBox.Select(yourText.IndexOf("portion"), "portion".Length);
txtRichTextBox.SelectionColor = YourColor;
txtRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman",FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic code:
    With RichTextBox1
                .SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                .AppendText("Blue text")
                .SelectionColor = Color.Black
                .AppendText(" black text")
            End With

Comment: Just give some better format and explanation to your answer