# Color a specific word from a rich text box?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, code-editor

I have found many tutorials on this. But there's some thing i don't like with them. There's many bugs, for example when you input the word you want to be colored and remove it, the rest of the input still being the custom color.

I'm making a code editor in C#, if you could help me with this problem, i would really appreciate it! Or if it was another way to do this?
THANKS!

Comment: [Color specific words in RichtextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980554/color-specific-words-in-richtextbox)

Comment: [RichTextBox change color of certain words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965264/c-sharp-richtextbox-change-color-of-certain-words)

Comment: [How to color different words in a RichTextBox with different colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319546/how-to-color-different-words-in-a-richtextbox-with-different-colors)

Comment: [Selectively coloring text in RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455713/selectively-coloring-text-in-richtextbox)

Comment: [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

Comment: [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)

Comment: If you delete too few characters the color is still there, as desigend.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is getting fed up